# Why is 'is' returning true for a different instance in Python

Tags: python

This is a python beginner question:

```
class MyClass:
    variable = "test"

    def function(self):
        print("test")

X = MyClass()
Y = MyClass()

print (X.variable == Y.variable)    // expected true, works
print (X.variable is Y.variable)    // expected false, but return true; why?
```

Since there are two instances of the class, why is the second test with 'is' returning true since the variables should be difference instances?

Comment: Related: [How to avoid having class data shared among instances?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1680528)

Answer (score 1):

In the example you've provided, `variable` is a class attribute on `MyClass`. All instances of `MyClass` will share the same `variable` instance. If you want to provide an instance variable to an instance of the class, you would do so in the `__init__` method like so:

```
class MyClass:
    shared_var = "I'm a property on the class"

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_var = "I'm a property on an instance"
```

Note, however, that even if you were to do the following:

```
x = MyClass()
y = MyClass()
x.my_var is y.my_var # This will still be True!
```

This is because the two strings actually reference the same object in Python. You can see this by typing the following in a Python interpretor:

```
id('test')
id('test') # This will be the same as the one above!
```

Comment: I'm learning the syntax of python; so variables declared just below the class name are considered static? how do you set the variable as part of the instance of the class?

Comment: It is not a static method, but a "class attribute".

Comment: Whoops, good call @wim

Comment: @Thomas you would want to declare instance variables in the `__init__` method. I'll update my answer to provide an example.

Comment: @Thomas probably important to note, but *Python doesn't have variable declarations*

Answer (score 0):

Because  "variable" is class or static variable. If you define it inside method, you will be correct.  Please look here: [Are static class variables possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/are-static-class-variables-possible)

Comment: "Static variable" is barely a good name in C; it has no meaning whatsoever in Python. It's a class attribute.